# How to control shader node's key frame animation curve?

Tags: shaders, keyframes, shader-nodes, graph-editor

I can't find the keyframes of the animation curve of the *Shader Editor*'s *Mapping Node* within the *Graph Editor*.
I can see that the shader animates with a bezier curve behavior in *3d View* but I want to change it to linear curve. Unfortunately I can't find it in the *Graph Editor* so there's no way I can change this.

[image]

I hope to get advice. Thank you.

Comment: kindly open the dopesheet and expand summary, u should be able to see it there?

Comment: u don't need the graph editor if you want to change the bezier behavior to linear. just open the dope sheet and expand summary on the left. and make sure to select the shader node. then you can right click the first keyframe and change interpolation to linear

Comment: thank you. it very helpful

Comment: I'm curious. What version of Blender is that?  You should be seeing the  F-curve for the mapping node in your setup, so you might have hit a Blender bug.

Comment: thank you. the version is 2.83. I reopened scene now, then I could see curve today.